# How to optimise angular6 with loopback3 server with prerender?

Tags: angular6, loopback, prerender

I have a application running with loopback 3 with angular 6 build and I serve my application with static file provide by loopback 3 in ../client/dist. But the the seo are not improved and any pre-render are working and not optimised for Seo.

I already try rendertron but it's seem not working... The only solution I found is with angular universal but how run universal application with loopback ?

Thank's

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: not working because when I trie to share publication og:image og:title etc... Not appear ...